# Running plot in browser from Python script

Tags: html, python-2.7, plotly

I managed to integrate a [3D plot](https://plot.ly/~RPlotBot/3012) from plotly in a HTML page with the iframe tag which contains the link to the plot. I was wondering if I can get the same result without using the link, but with running the Python code of the plot. So the result will be the same plot in an iframe tag or div tag.

The HTML file contains these lines:

```
    <iframe link="false" width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://plot.ly/~RPlotBot/3012.embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

as for the Python script to create the plot, I placed it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chemseddineZ/408e019f9cb5a55169dedc9d3bb320b2).

Comment: Add some code, it would make helping you easier.

Comment: @nfnneil i edited the problem by adding the html code and a gist containing the python code for the plot